# Google Admin Reports API: Users Usage Report stats accuracy

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to use **Google Admin Reports API: Users Usage Report** to pull emails received/sent per user per day in our org's google app.

When I use Google APIs Explorer to pull my own stats for a particular day and compared it with real situation, it seems the number is far off.

For example, on Sunday, 7th Dec 2014, I only sent out one email. But the stats shows there were 4 emails sent out by me on that day.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You should get the same results than searching in Gmail:

`in:sent from:me after:2014/12/07 before:2014/12/08`

The missing bit is the time zone the server is using which in my research it is always Pacific Standard Time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you:

- Send out any calendar invitations that day? (1 email per attendee)
- Share any Google Drive files/folders that day (1 email per file shared)
- Send mail from a Google Group

there are likely other actions you may have performed in other Google Apps which caused emails to go out in your name and count against your quota but not necessarily show in your Sent folder.

If you'd like for these messages to appear in your Sent folder, turn on [Comprehensive Storage](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3547347?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks Jay, I've turned on Comprehensive Storage feature.

Comment: However, I still doubt the accuracy of the stats. For instance, I have 3 emails in my sent folder on 5th Dec 2014 while the stat shows 0. I used my accounts time zone for the date field as suggested from this [document](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-usage-users)